# Find all elements in page by passing class name in javascript function without using getElementsBy* or any lib function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find all elements in the page by passing class name in this function, I getting all elements as arrays object but I need only those elements those are having my className only.

```
    var custSearch = function (element, className) {
    var elementsArray  = [];
    // add spaces 
    var q = ' ' + className + ' ';
    (function recFind (node) {
    // Looping through all the child nodes
     for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
      var currentNode  = node.childNodes[i];
      var currentClass = currentNode.className;

      // check if current class match with param class 
      if ((' '+currentClass+' ').indexOf(q)) {
        elementsArray.push(currentNode);
      }


      currentNode.childNodes && recFind(currentNode);
    }
   })(element);

  return elementsArray;
  }; 
custSearch(document, 'spch');
```

I don't want to use getElementsByClassName function but I want similar result, this above function should give me exact result but I am not finding what I am doing wrong, Can someone tell me if I am making any logical error?

HTML is like this

```
<div class="spch s2fp-h" style="display:none" id="spch"><div class="spchc" id="spchc"><div class="_o3"><div class="_AM"><span class="_CMb" id="spchl"></span><span class="button" id="spchb"><div class="_wPb"><span class="_AUb"></span><div class="_Fjd"><span class="_oXb"></span><span class="_dWb"></span></div></div></span></div><div class="_gjb"><span class="spcht" id="spchi" style="color:#777"></span><span class="spcht" id="spchf" style="color:#000"></span></div><div class="google-logo"></div></div><div class="_ypc"><div class="_zpc"></div></div></div><div class="close-button" id="spchx">×</div></div>
```

Comment: if you have something which makes your work easier, why don't use that? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: @Bharadwaj I am preparing for some exam that's y I am trying to do it without predefined functions.

Comment: Oh, note that if the sting isn't found, *indexOf* returns -1 so `(' '+currentClass+' ').indexOf(q)` evaluates to true. The only ones that won't be in the array are those where the string starts at the first character (i.e. those that have the class as the first one in their class list).

Comment: *"Can someone tell me if I am making any logical error?"* - Yes. It is illogical to refuse to use getElementsByClassName() for this.

Comment: @RobG Oh I just need to add !  if (!(' '+currentClass+' ').indexOf(q))  I think now it will work.

Comment: No, you need to test that it is not equal to -1. Using the not operator doesn't do that.

Comment: if there is a single document you can use document.querySelectorAll(".vote-down-off")

Comment: @Shad No you need to check if `(' '+currentClass+' ').indexOf(q) >= 0` then this code seems just fine. @RobG It's a recursive function called immediately. Well played

Comment: @bigΩmega Thanks it is working as expected now, I had error in  this condition only.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function myGetElementsByClassName(className) {

    var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  var out = [];

  for( var i=0, len=nodes.length; i<len; i++) {
    if( nodes[i].classList.contains( className ) ) {
        out.push( nodes[i] );
    }
  }

  return out;

}
```

Comment: can you please explain why querySelectorAll cant be used in this case?

Comment: Yep that can also be used but I think OP is not looking for the easy solution.

Comment: OP is just using DOM to play with tree traversal. This is a not a production code guys, just hacking around

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't use any of getElementsBy__  function. @Umer Hayyat  I have already mentioned in the comment above the reason for writing it without using predefined functions.